# jenkins kubernetes-plugin archive/junit

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a multi-container job which runs on k8s via kubernetes-jenkins plugin. everything works great but I am unable to `junit` or `archiveArtifacts` anything. I suspect it's because it exists only in the container but not sure. code is below:

```
def label = "foo-${UUID.randomUUID().toString()}"

podTemplate(
        label: label,
        containers: [
                containerTemplate(name: 'c1', image: 'c1'),
                containerTemplate(name: 'c2', image: 'c2'),
                containerTemplate(name: 'c3', image: 'c3'),
        ],
        volumes: [
                hostPathVolume(mountPath: '/var/run/docker.sock', hostPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'),
        ],
) {
    node(label) {
        stage('test') {
            container('c1') {
                sh """
                  cd /some-path
                  ./generate-junit-xml
                """

                archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: '/some-path/foo.xml'

                sh "cat /some-path/foo.xml"
            }
        }
    }
}

def label = "foo-${UUID.randomUUID().toString()}"

podTemplate(
        label: label,
        namespace: 'jenkins',
        imagePullSecrets: [ 'myreg' ],
        containers: [
                containerTemplate(name: 'c1', image: 'c1'),
                containerTemplate(name: 'c2', image: 'c2'),
                containerTemplate(name: 'c3', image: 'c3'),
        ],
        volumes: [
                hostPathVolume(mountPath: '/var/run/docker.sock', hostPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'),
        ],
) {
    node(label) {
        stage('test') {
            container('c1') {
                sh """
                  ./something-that-generates-junit-foo-xml
                """

                archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: '/abs/path/to/foo.xml'

                sh "cat /abs/path/to/foo.xml"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

build log shows the following output:

```
[Pipeline] archiveArtifacts
Archiving artifacts
WARN: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "/some-path/foo.xml". Configuration error?
[Pipeline] sh
[test-pipeline] Running shell script
+ cat /some-path/unittest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>...</xml>
```

would appreciate your help!

Comment: I think you need to add all steps in the first container.

Answer (score 0):

both `junit` and `archiveArtifacts` can only archive files that are inside WORKSPACE, containers do not shave any volumes with host (where jenkins WORKSPACE is) unless you explicitly do so

I solved this with:
 - adding additional volume where I save files

```
hostPathVolume(hostPath: '/tmp', mountPath: '/tmp')
```

- copying files from `tmp` to WORKSPACE with [File Operations Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/File+Operations+Plugin)

```
dir("/tmp/screenshots") {
    fileOperations([fileCopyOperation(excludes: '', flattenFiles: true, includes: '*.png', targetLocation: "${WORKSPACE}/screenshots")])
}
```

- archiving artifacts

```
archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: 'screenshots/**/*.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

copying the artifacts to the Jenkins workspace will solve it

```
age('test') {
        container('c1') {
            sh """
              ./something-that-generates-junit-foo-xml
            """
            sh 'cp /abs/path/to/foo.xml ${WORKSPACE}/abs/foo.xml'
            archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: 'abs/foo.xml'

            sh "cat /abs/path/to/foo.xml"
        }
```

you can copy the dir if you need all the dir content

```
sh 'cp -r /abs/path/to/ ${WORKSPACE}/abs/to'
archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: 'abs/to/*.xml'
```